# SQL Server: set 2 column into 1 variable from variable table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone check what is wrong with this codes? I already check the other questions for reference but its still not working.

[image]

```
declare @sourceTable varchar(500)
declare @year varchar(22)
declare @month varchar(3)
declare @test varchar(12)
declare @result varchar(8)
declare @index int

declare @string varchar(15)
set @string = (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 REPLACE(dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW, '|', 0), CHAR(9), '') FROM #temp1)
set @test = (select UPPER(convert(datetime,substring(@string,2,charindex('-',@string,1)-2))))
set @month =(left(@test,3))

set @year = (right(@test,5))

set @result = @month + @year
-- select @result

set @sourceTable = 'gen_048_'+@result
select @sourceTable

declare @string2 varchar(255)
set @string2 = (select convert(varchar(55),refdate)+''-''+convert(varchar(55),refcount) FROM @sourceTable)
select @string2
```

This is the error

> Must declare the table variable "@sourceTable".

Comment: What is the value of `@test`? And what do you get now? What did you *expect* to get instead?

Comment: First mention what's wrong with your current code

Comment: Need Dynamic Query

Comment: Sorry, please check it again I already put the missing codes

Comment: you have to declare the variable `@sourceTable`.

Comment: Combine sagi's and prdp's answers to solve your problem.

Comment: Yah, Prdp saves the day! thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need dynamic query

```
SET @string2 = 'select convert(varchar(55),refdate)+''-''+convert(varchar(55),refcount) FROM '
               + Quotename(@sourceTable)

EXEC (@string2)
```

Comment: Thanks~! this one works just fine. my only problem now is how to update the rows of this reference number.

Answer (score 1):

You are not declaring @sourcetable , the error shouts it loud and clear.

Add this At the beginning :

```
declare @sourcetable varchar(50)
```

Also, I believe you need to use dynamic SQL for this sort of queries and variable using.

Comment: Yes I declared the @sourceTable that is why its kinda weird that I still got that error. I just forgot to put it there.

Answer (score 0):

```
set @string2 = (select convert(varchar(55),refdate)+'-'+convert(varchar(55),refcount) FROM @sourceTable)
```

Comment: I already did this one, this is the exact string from the other question but its not working. This is the error `Must declare the table variable "@sourceTable".`

Comment: obviously from the code you provided, don't have such variable : @sourceTable

Comment: it seem "@sourceTable" is varchar? so you add one more line something like this. ==> declare "@sourceTable" varchar(15)

Comment: ok then, this line "set @string2 = (select convert(varchar(55),refdate)+''-''+convert(varchar(55),refcount) FROM @sourceTable)" 
you use "@sourceTable" as a table? what is the column?